# Rosbag doesn't record cmd_vel on remote master

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running Electric on Natty and have the following peculiar issue.

When I run rosbag -a on the above host, the bag output records cmd_vel. However, when I collect rosbag output after setting ROS_MASTER_URI to a different host (which runs diamondback on Lucid), I don't get cmd_vel recorded. Even

`shell> rosbag record cmd_vel -a`

fails to record cmd_vel in such a case, although all other topics are logged. Note that cmd_vel is being published always.
What could be the problem?

**Updated after Lorenzo's answer**  rostopic echo /cmd_vel gives the right output in such a case.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36364/rosbag-doesn%27t-record-cmd_vel-on-remote-master/) by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 365 on 2012-06-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-06-12**:
Probably not the cause, but mixing Electric and Diamondback in a single ROS graph is a bad idea and not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like a network problem to me. To prove, check if `rostopic echo /cmd_vel` also doesn't work. Have a look at [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup) page for more information on debugging network issues.

**Edit**: Also try `rosbag record cmd_vel` instead of `rosbag record -a` to make sure that it hasn't something to do with the -a flag.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0